Unreal Engine 5.4.1 freezes every second
I encountered a problem in Unreal Engine 5.4.1, when starting an empty project with a first-person template, the whole Unreal Engine starts to slow down a lot (freezes every second). At the same time the processor and video card are loaded by 3-4%. I also noticed that the previous project with a template from the 3rd person works fine. Tried to update the drivers - did not help. Also changed DirectX from 12 to 11, and also to no avail. Windows 10 version 22H2.
Reinstalling Windows didn't help either.

We can help with bugs and technical issues with your game, but generally can't provide technical support for commercial products like the Unreal Engine itself. Have you posted your issue on the Unreal support community? https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/support

@Kevin I'll try installing a later version of Unreal Engine, and if my problem doesn't go away, I'll post to the Unreal community.
